# Please how do I port this Curl request to Android?

Tags: java, android, curl

I am  trying to get, form my Android Application, the PayPal Oauth refresh_token.

Like in this link https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/future_payments_server.md#request

The request to achieve that is, in Curl, the following:

```
curl 'https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token' \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Authorization: Basic QWZV...==" \
-d 'grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code=EBYhRW3ncivudQn8UopLp4A28...'
```

**Please how do i do it form my Android App?**

I have tried this way:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");

    try {
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
        httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic QWZV...==");
        StringEntity se=new StringEntity("grant_type=authorization_code&response_type=token&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&code="+authorization.getAuthorizationCode());
        httppost.setEntity(se);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

**But I get a 400 BAD REQUEST response.**

Comment: Use HttpUrlConnection or Apache Http client, then let us know what didn't work.

Comment: @Mighter thanks Mighter, please see my edit. Bye. LISA

Comment: @LisaAnne is it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Type` header you are trying is completely wrong. It is not posting any data `-d` to the server. So you get bad request error.

Replace your one:

```
httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

With below one(also notice the difference between the two):

```
httppost.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: thank you very much Sabuj, I tried with your modification, unfortunatelely again 400 BAD REQUEST  :-((((

Comment: @LisaAnne lol. You need to provide us the response that you got. For example the output of `response.getEntity().getContent()`. Please update your question with this response.

Comment: you are right, the `response.getEntity().getContent()` reads: `{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Both client id and client secret are required parameters"}` therefore your method is working, I will have to fix the rest...Thanks!!!

Comment: @SabujHassan is it content or Content